# Picasso Showing the Error Path Must Not Be Empty?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, picasso

I am trying to fetching image from firebase. so when there is no image in firebase i want that my app logo will be set there. but my app is crashing and throwing the error into a log-cat.

I tried using if-else condition. and also on Success and on Error Methods. but did't worked fine.

```
private static final String Earnings_Freebies = "EARNINGS_FREEBIES";

    private Earnings_Freebies list;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.earnings_freebies);

list = (Earnings_Freebies) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable(Earnings_Freebies);

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(list.getmImageView())){
            m_EF_ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.app_logo);
            mProgressBarEF.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(list.getmImageView())
                .into(m_EF_ImageView, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        mProgressBarEF.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mFailedImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        mProgressBarEF.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mFailedImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                });
```

I want when there is error. or i forget to put image into firebase then app logo will automatically set into Image-view.

Comment: and may i ask what your **Earnings_Freebies** looks like?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code. If not helpful then let me know a bit more about **Earnings_Freebies** model.

Make sure you were using latest dependency of Picasso.

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.earnings_freebies);

    list = (Earnings_Freebies) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable(Earnings_Freebies);

    if (list == null && TextUtils.isEmpty(list.getmImageView())){
        m_EF_ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.app_logo);
        mProgressBarEF.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) // can also be a drawable
                .into(m_EF_ImageView);
    } else {
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(list.getmImageView())
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) // can also be a drawable
                .into(m_EF_ImageView);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way:

```
private static final String Earnings_Freebies = "EARNINGS_FREEBIES";

    private Earnings_Freebies list;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.earnings_freebies);

        list = (Earnings_Freebies) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable(Earnings_Freebies);

        if (list != null && list.getmImageView() != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(list.getmImageView())){
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(list.getmImageView())
                .into(m_EF_ImageView, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        mProgressBarEF.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mFailedImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        mProgressBarEF.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mFailedImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                });
        }else{
              Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(R.drawable.app_logo)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.app_logo)
                .into(m_EF_ImageView);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Picasso supports both download and error placeholders as optional features.

2) An error drawable will be used in case where there’s a failure in loading the image. In this case the interim placeholder image will be replaced by the error drawable that’s placed inside .error() method, where you can display your app's icon image in case of error.

```
  Picasso.with(this).load("https://someImageURL")
                  .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) // Your app's icon image displayed on error
                  .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder) // some placeholder image
                  .into(imageView, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Log.d("TAG", "onSuccess");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "An error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```